# Correr un script de python desde raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, crontab

Buen día presento este problema

Tengo este código que aquí mismo me dieron la respuesta es sobre publicar temperatura y humedad lo hago desde un script de python corriendo en una raspberry pi 4 y ya esta arrojando los datos todo esta bien pero ahora quiero hacerlo mediante un crontab pero no logro hacerlo correctamente

Este es código que tengo ya funcionando

```
import os
import time
import sys
import random as random
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import json

THINGSBOARD_HOST = ''
ACCESS_TOKEN = ''

# Data capture and upload interval in seconds. Less interval will eventually hang the DHT22.
INTERVAL=2

sensor_data = {'temperature': 0, 'humidity': 0}

next_reading = time.time() 

client = mqtt.Client()

# Set access token
client.username_pw_set(ACCESS_TOKEN)

# Connect to ThingsBoard using default MQTT port and 60 seconds keepalive interval
client.connect(THINGSBOARD_HOST, 8080, 60)

client.loop_start()

try:
    while True:
        humidity = random.uniform(0, 100)
        temperature = random.uniform(10, 60)
        humidity = round(humidity, 2)
        temperature = round(temperature, 2)
        print(u"Temperature: {:g}\u00b0C, Humidity: {:g}%".format(temperature, humidity))
        sensor_data['temperature'] = temperature
        sensor_data['humidity'] = humidity

        # Sending humidity and temperature data to ThingsBoard
        client.publish('v1/devices/me/telemetry', json.dumps(sensor_data), 1)

        next_reading += INTERVAL
        sleep_time = next_reading-time.time()
        if sleep_time > 0:
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

client.loop_stop()
client.disconnect()
```

Asi es como se mira en la terminal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi es como segun instale el crontab
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad no se si lo hice bien o algo e igual si me pudieran decir como hacerlo correcto para que el script siempre este corriendo una vez que se enciende la raspberry pi

Muchas gracias

Comment: Las cosas que ejecutas desde crontab tienen que terminar. Tu script no termina nunca. No necesitas crontab para eso; tienes que convertir el script en un servicio (manejado con systemctrl y/o service)

Comment: Además, crontab y servicios ejecutan desvinculados del terminal, por lo que el `print` no lo vas a ver por consola. Tampoco puedes leer el teclado.

Answer (score 1):

Crontab está hecho para correr programas a intervalos, programas que parten, ejecutan alguna tarea y terminan.

Si quieres que algo empiece a correr tan pronto boote Raspeberry, necesitas programarlo con `systemd`

**Crear un script ejecutable**

Para demostración, tenemos este script llamado `daemon.py` que simplemente graba una línea en `syslog` cada un minuto:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import syslog
import time

syslog.syslog("THX: Inicio del sistema")
while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    syslog.syslog("THX: tick")
```

Punto importante es la primera línea:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Esta es una convención en Unix: la primera línea empieza con "#!" y te dice que programa usar para ejecutar el script. Como es un script python, ponemos el path completo hasta el ejecutable Python.

También marcamos el script como ejecutable:

```
chmod a+x daemon.py
```

Al ser ejecutable, lo podemos lanzar desde la línea de comandos y comprobar que efectivamente está funcionando:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

produce:

```
Feb  9 22:37:40 pi daemon.py: THX: Inicio del sistema
Feb  9 22:38:40 pi daemon.py: THX: tick
```

OK. Funciona.

**Crear archivo de servicio**

Hay que crear un archivo que describe el servicio para entregarlo a `systemd`. En tu directorio crea `daemon.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Raspberry Temperature Monitor
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/candid/daemon.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/candid
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
User=candid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Las únicas cosas que hay que cambiar son:

Description: El texto que mostrara systemd.

ExecStart: El path al script.

WorkingDirectory: El directorio de trabajo para el script.

User: La cuenta de usuario con la que se ejecutar el script. Debería ser una cuenta específica (no root), con los privilegios mínimos para acceder al ejecutable y su directorio.

Systemd mantiene todos las definiciones de servicio en `/lib/systemd/system` (el path puede variar según la distribución). Hay que copiar el descriptor para allá y ejecutar un reload para que systemd se de por enterado:

```
sudo cp daemon.service /lib/systemd/system
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

**Ejecución**
Para iniciar, pausar o detener el servicio se usa `systemctl`

```
sudo systemctl start daemon.service
```

Lanza el servicio. Para preguntar por el estado:

```
>sudo systemctl status daemon.service
* daemon.service - Raspberry Temperature Monitor
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/daemon.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-02-09 22:18:11 -03; 15min ago
 Main PID: 12808 (daemon.py)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2063)
   CGroup: /system.slice/daemon.service
           `-12808 /usr/bin/python /home/candid/daemon.py

Feb 09 22:24:11 pi.home daemon.py[12808]: THX: tick
Feb 09 22:25:11 pi.home daemon.py[12808]: THX: tick
Feb 09 22:26:11 pi.home daemon.py[12808]: THX: tick
Feb 09 22:27:11 pi.home daemon.py[12808]: THX: tick
Feb 09 22:28:12 pi.home daemon.py[12808]: THX: tick
Feb 09 22:29:12 pi.home daemon.py[12808]: THX: tick
Feb 09 22:30:12 pi.home daemon.py[12808]: THX: tick
Feb 09 22:31:12 pi.home daemon.py[12808]: THX: tick
Feb 09 22:32:12 pi.home daemon.py[12808]: THX: tick
Feb 09 22:33:12 pi.home daemon.py[12808]: THX: tick
```

que nos muestra el servicio andando.

Mirando el syslog:

```
Feb  9 22:18:11 pi daemon.py: THX: Inicio del sistema
Feb  9 22:19:11 pi daemon.py: THX: tick
Feb  9 22:20:11 pi daemon.py: THX: tick
Feb  9 22:21:11 pi daemon.py: THX: tick
Feb  9 22:22:11 pi daemon.py: THX: tick
Feb  9 22:23:11 pi daemon.py: THX: tick
Feb  9 22:24:11 pi daemon.py: THX: tick
```